# CP decomposition as a special case of Tucker decomposition

Tags: tensors, book-recommendation, kronecker-product, tensor-decomposition

I am reading this [article](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2017/cmsc396H/papers/tensors.pdf) "Tensor Decompositions and Applications" by Kolda and Bader.  On page 21, it says:

> ...CP [decomposition] can be viewed as a special case of Tucker [decomposition] where the core tensor is superdiagonal and $P = Q = R$...

But there's no proof to back the statement.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The proof in ([Kolda and Bader, 2009](https://www.kolda.net/publication/TensorReview.pdf)) may be left out since the authors consider it trivial.

##### Definitions

*(CP decomposition)*
Let $\textbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J \times K}$ be a 3-way tensor.
*CP decomposition* of $\textbf{X}$ can be written elementwise as
$$
\textbf{X} \approx \sum_{r = 1}^{R} a_{ir} b_{jr} c_{kr}, 
~~~ \text{for} ~~~
i = 1,\ldots,I, ~~ j = 1,\ldots,J, ~~ k = 1,\ldots,K,
$$
where $R$ is a positive integer, $\textbf{a}_r \in \mathbb{R}^{I}$,
$\textbf{b}_r \in \mathbb{R}^{J}$, and $\textbf{c}_r \in \mathbb{R}^{K}$
for $r = 1,\ldots,R$.

*(Tucker decomposition)*
Let $\textbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J \times K}$ be a 3-way tensor.
*Tucker decomposition* of $\textbf{X}$ can be written elementwise as
$$
\textbf{X} \approx 
\sum_{p = 1}^{P} \sum_{q = 1}^{Q} \sum_{r = 1}^{R} g_{pqr} a_{ip} b_{jq} c_{kr}, 
~~~ \text{for} ~~~
i = 1,\ldots,I, ~~ j = 1,\ldots,J, ~~ k = 1,\ldots,K,
$$
where $P,Q,R$ is a positive integer,
$\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{I \times P}$,
$\textbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{J \times Q}$, and $\textbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times R}$, and
$\textbf{G} \in \mathbb{R}^{P \times Q \times R}$ is the *core tensor*.

*(Superdiagonal tensor)* A tensor $\textbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{I_1 \times I_2 \times \ldots \times I_N}$ is *superdiagonal* if
$$
x_{i_1 i_2 \ldots i_N} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & ~~\text{if} ~~ i_1 = i_2 = \ldots = i_N \\
0, & ~~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

##### Statement and Its Proof

**Statement.**
CP decomposition can be viewed as a special case of Tucker where the core tensor is superdiagonal and $P = Q = R$.

> **Proof.**
> The proof uses simple algebra to show that an arbitrary Tucker decomposition with superdiagonal core tensor can be reduced to a CP decomposition. Let $[\![\textbf{G}; \textbf{A}, \textbf{B}, \textbf{C}]\!]$ be a Tucker decomposition that satisfies
> $$
> \tilde{\textbf{X}} = 
> \sum_{p = 1}^{P} \sum_{q = 1}^{Q} \sum_{r = 1}^{R} g_{pqr} a_{ip} b_{jq} c_{kr}, 
> ~~~ \text{for} ~~~
> i = 1,\ldots,I, ~~ j = 1,\ldots,J, ~~ k = 1,\ldots,K,
> $$
> where $\textbf{G}$ is superdiagonal
> and
> $\tilde{\textbf{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J \times K}$ be a 3-way tensor. Then
> this equation can be rewritten as
> \begin{align}
> \tilde{\textbf{X}}
> & = \sum_{p = 1}^{P} \sum_{q = 1}^{Q} \sum_{r = 1}^{R} g_{pqr} a_{ip} b_{jq} c_{kr} \\
> & = \sum_{p = 1}^{P} 
> \left( \sum_{q = 1, q \neq p}^{Q} \sum_{r = 1}^{R} g_{pqr} a_{ip} b_{jq} c_{kr}
> + \sum_{r = 1}^{R} g_{ppr} a_{ip} b_{jp} c_{kr} \right)  \\
> & = \sum_{p = 1}^{P} \sum_{r = 1}^{R} g_{ppr} a_{ip} b_{jp} c_{kr} \\
> & = \sum_{p = 1}^{P} 
> \left( \sum_{r = 1, r \neq p}^{R} g_{ppr} a_{ip} b_{jp} c_{kr} 
> + g_{ppp} a_{ip} b_{jp} c_{kp} \right) \\
> & = \sum_{p = 1}^{P} a_{ip} b_{jp} c_{kp}.  
> \end{align}
> Then, $[\![\textbf{A}, \textbf{B}, \textbf{C}]\!]$ is a CP decomposition of $\tilde{\textbf{X}}$.

Kolda, T. G., & Bader, B. W. (2009). Tensor decompositions and applications. SIAM review, 51(3), 455-500. doi: [10.1137/07070111X](https://doi.org/10.1137/07070111X)